Generating Fantasy Cricket Team using Java
I am little new in android and java and trying to create function which generate random cricket team of 11 players with captain and vice captain with following strict rule like

min and max players for each role,
max players from one team
if contest is small, 80% player need to be consistent and 20% risky players and if contest is mega, 60% player will be consistent and 40% risky players
all teams should be unique
random players combination based on team like 7-4,4-7,5-6 and 6-5 etc

Now I have made function like this:
private void generateTeams(List<Player> captains, List<Player> viceCaptains) {
    if (!canGenerateTeams()) {
        showErrorDialog(getString(R.string.error), getString(R.string.unable_to_generate_teams));
        return;
    }

    int consistentRatio = contestType == 2 ? 80 : 60; // Small contest: 80-20, Mega contest: 60-40

    // Prepare player pools
    List<Player> allPlayers = new ArrayList<>(PlayersViewModelCricketAI.getBothTeamsPlayers().getValue());
    allPlayers.removeAll(selectedPlayerOut); // Remove locked-out players

    // Sort players by credits (higher credits first for consistent players)
    allPlayers.sort((p1, p2) -> Double.compare(p2.getPlayerCredit(), p1.getPlayerCredit()));

    // Divide players into consistent and risky groups
    int splitIndex = (consistentRatio * allPlayers.size()) / 100;
    List<Player> consistentPlayers = new ArrayList<>(allPlayers.subList(0, splitIndex));
    List<Player> riskyPlayers = new ArrayList<>(allPlayers.subList(splitIndex, allPlayers.size()));

    // Initialize team generation parameters
    List<Team> generatedTeams = new ArrayList<>();
    Set<String> generatedTeamSignatures = new HashSet<>();
    int maxPlayersFromOneTeam = MAX_PLAYERS_ONE_TEAM;

    int requiredTeams = totalTeamsToCreate;
    int attempts = 0;
    int maxAttempts = (requiredTeams * 50);

    Random random = new Random();

    while (generatedTeams.size() < requiredTeams && attempts < maxAttempts) {
        attempts++;

        List<Player> teamPlayers = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<Integer> teamPlayerIds = new HashSet<>();
        int team1Count = 0, team2Count = 0;

        // Randomly choose a valid team combination (e.g., 7-4, 6-5, 5-6)
        int team1Limit = 4 + random.nextInt(4); // Adjust range as needed
        int team2Limit = TOTAL_PLAYERS - team1Limit;

        // Add locked-in players
        for (Player player : selectedPlayerIn) {
            if (teamPlayers.size() < TOTAL_PLAYERS && !teamPlayerIds.contains(player.getPlayerId())) {
                if (validatePositionConstraints(player, teamPlayers)) {
                    teamPlayers.add(player);
                    teamPlayerIds.add(player.getPlayerId());

                    if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 1) team1Count++;
                    if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 2) team2Count++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Add captain and vice-captain
        Player captain = captains.get(random.nextInt(captains.size()));
        Player viceCaptain = viceCaptains.get(random.nextInt(viceCaptains.size()));

        // Ensure captain and vice-captain are not the same
        if (captain.getPlayerId() != viceCaptain.getPlayerId()) {
            if (!teamPlayerIds.contains(captain.getPlayerId()) && validatePositionConstraints(captain, teamPlayers)) {
                teamPlayers.add(captain);
                teamPlayerIds.add(captain.getPlayerId());
                if (captain.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 1) team1Count++;
                if (captain.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 2) team2Count++;
            }

            if (!teamPlayerIds.contains(viceCaptain.getPlayerId()) && validatePositionConstraints(viceCaptain, teamPlayers)) {
                teamPlayers.add(viceCaptain);
                teamPlayerIds.add(viceCaptain.getPlayerId());
                if (viceCaptain.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 1) team1Count++;
                if (viceCaptain.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 2) team2Count++;
            }
        }else{
            continue;
        }

        // Fill remaining slots with consistent players
        for (Player player : consistentPlayers) {
            if (teamPlayers.size() >= TOTAL_PLAYERS) break;

            if (!teamPlayerIds.contains(player.getPlayerId()) && validatePositionConstraints(player, teamPlayers)) {
                if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 1 && team1Count >= team1Limit) continue;
                if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 2 && team2Count >= team2Limit) continue;

                teamPlayers.add(player);
                teamPlayerIds.add(player.getPlayerId());
                if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 1) team1Count++;
                if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 2) team2Count++;
            }
        }

        // Fill remaining slots with risky players
        for (Player player : riskyPlayers) {
            if (teamPlayers.size() >= TOTAL_PLAYERS) break;

            if (!teamPlayerIds.contains(player.getPlayerId()) && validatePositionConstraints(player, teamPlayers)) {
                if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 1 && team1Count >= team1Limit) continue;
                if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 2 && team2Count >= team2Limit) continue;

                teamPlayers.add(player);
                teamPlayerIds.add(player.getPlayerId());
                if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 1) team1Count++;
                if (player.getPlayerTeamNumber() == 2) team2Count++;
            }
        }

        if (validateTeam(teamPlayers, maxPlayersFromOneTeam)) {
            List<Integer> playerIds = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Player p : teamPlayers) {
                playerIds.add(p.getPlayerId());
            }
            Collections.sort(playerIds);
            String teamSignature = playerIds + "-" + captain.getPlayerId() + "-" + viceCaptain.getPlayerId();

            // Check uniqueness
            if (!generatedTeamSignatures.contains(teamSignature)) {
                Team team = new Team();
                team.players = new ArrayList<>(teamPlayers);
                team.captainId = captain.getPlayerId();
                team.viceCaptainId = viceCaptain.getPlayerId();
                generatedTeams.add(team);
                generatedTeamSignatures.add(teamSignature); // Track this team
            }
        }
    }

    Log.e("RESULTS","REQUIRED TEAMS: "+ totalTeamsToCreate +" GENERATED TEAMS: "+ generatedTeams.size()+" ATTEMPTS:"+attempts);

    String content = getResources().getString(R.string.teams_count_confirmation, generatedTeams.size());
    showSuccessDialog(content, generatedTeams);
}

and log result is like this
2024-12-01 09:51:07.597 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:30
2024-12-01 09:51:11.173 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:40
2024-12-01 09:51:14.302 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:32
2024-12-01 09:51:16.138 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:37
2024-12-01 09:51:17.869 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:28
2024-12-01 09:51:19.641 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:37
2024-12-01 09:51:21.848 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:35
2024-12-01 09:51:23.616 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:33
2024-12-01 09:51:25.495 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:48
2024-12-01 09:51:27.400 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 16 ATTEMPTS:1000
2024-12-01 09:51:30.288 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:34
2024-12-01 09:51:32.172 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:32
2024-12-01 09:51:33.722 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:39
2024-12-01 09:51:36.133 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:25
2024-12-01 09:51:37.877 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:29
2024-12-01 09:51:39.724 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 20 ATTEMPTS:39
2024-12-01 09:51:42.020 25080-25080 RESULTS                 com.example.teams                   E  REQUIRED TEAMS: 20 GENERATED TEAMS: 16 ATTEMPTS:1000

as you can see sometime its generate required teams in just fewer attempts and sometime even 1000 attempt not generating enough required teams, there enough players but making random thing causing duplicate teams and attempt getting failed, so I want improve my code so it can generate required random things with strictly following my rules. Let me know if someone here can help me for the same
Thanks!

Hello Neha, The truth is that I didn't understand anything about Cricket, maybe it would be very helpful, if you explained in more detail what you are looking for, I ask myself questions like: "do the participants have credit?, how does that influence the team creation?, what does it mean that the teams are 7-4,4-7,5-6 and 6-5?".
